# Titan with remote server?

Tags: java, gremlin, titan, tinkerpop

I have a large project written using the Titan Java API: http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/javadoc/1.0.0/

I want to use a remote Gremlin server rather than having the application open its own connection to the database.  Can I configure Titan to use a remote server?  If not, would I need to convert the project to using the Gremlin driver (http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-java)?  How would I go about translating everything?

Comment: If downvoting please comment why...

Answer (score 1):

So Titan actually deploys a version of the [gremlin server](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server). This exposes a REST api which you can make use of.

[Here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html) is an example showing how to start the gremlin server and connecting to it remotely with the gremlin console.

[Here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_connecting_via_rest) is an example of issuing connections over the REST API.

The reason this is a bit confusing to follow is that Titan actually provides the gremlin server but leaves it up to you to read this section of the [tinkerpop docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server) to figure out how to use it.

By the way. Titan is no longer being maintained, you should consider changing to [Janus Graph](http://janusgraph.org/) which is a fork of Titan that is still being maintained and developed.